# Popen.communicate() returns (None, None) even if script print results

Tags: python, shell

I have problem with Popen.communicate().

I have script which return string.

Then I have wrote second script which takes that variable.

```
v = "./myscript arg1 arg2"
com = subprocess.Popen(v, shell=True).communicate()
print com
```

com returns (None, None). The point is that I can print inside first script the results,
shell print result as well. I can't just assign that print to variable.

Of course first script returns value, not print it.

Comment: If you're going to use the standard output to communicate results from `myscript` back to your Python script, wouldn't you need `myscript` to actually print something to STDOUT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the `Popen` object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

Hence, create the `Popen` object with:

```
subprocess.Popen("./myscript arg1 arg2", shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's one step foward, but now i'm getting empty string -.-

Comment: Lazy answer doesn't specify where to add `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE`.

Comment: @N8TRO the same lazy answer is given in Python Official docs too!!

Comment: Unfortunately `stdout=PIPE` prevents real time output from being displayed on the screen. What is the easiest way to get both?

Comment: unfortunately that's a separate concern in python; other questions attempt it to address it. i think basically instead of communicate() you read directly from subprocess.stdout as a file object, and manually send it to the display.