# how to return the result from subprocess.popen form the following code

Tags: python

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import inspect

def run_process(cmd_args):
    with subprocess.popen(cmd_args) as p:
        return (p.communicate())

res = run_process(cmd_args);

if 'with' in inspect.getsource(run_process):
    print("'with' used in 'run_process' function definition.\n")

if 'popen' in inspect.getsource(run_process):
    print("'popen' used in 'run_process' function definition.\n")
    print('process output : %s\n' % (res.decode("utf-8")))

    f.close()
```

i get an error at `res.decode` saying `none type has no attribute decode`. could some one suggest how to handle `run_process` function?

Comment: when you say result what do u mean by that ? do you want to see the output of the popen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popen.communicate() returns (None, None) even if script print results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904943/popen-communicate-returns-none-none-even-if-script-print-results)

Comment: @toheedNiaz my script is throwing an error at this line " print('process output : %s\n' % (res.decode("utf-8")))"

Comment: because your `.communicate` is returning None . If you just want to read the out put then i can help you .

Comment: i got the solution thank you